# local php files will not work

Tags: php

I have to do a php project. I done php before so I understand the syntax for the most part. Just for a test, I made a file.php and in it I wrote:

```
   <html>

   <body>

   <?php echo "helloWorld"; ?>

   </body>

   </html>
```

Well it won't display. The screen is blank. I tried it in chrome, firefox, IE and nothing wants to dispaly. Actually in IE, the source is displayed which is wierd. I also tried it without all the html and just used xampp to render it. It will not work. If I right click tho in the browser and view source, the code is there. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: See webserver error logs, but for first look at `view HTML source` in your browser

Comment: How are you running your source code? It sounds like PHP is not enabled.

Comment: Are you running a web server with PHP installed? Opening a local file directly in a web browser will not cause your script to be magically executed. You must use a web server.

Comment: I'm just using xampp. Apache, MySQL running. Thats how I use to do it.

Comment: it seems that you don't have the php apache handler activated in httpd.conf...

Comment: how can I check if the apache handler is activated

Comment: Seems your apache server cannot run php script, install apache2-mod-php or better use XAMPP or WAMP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're new to setting up your own server, i would recommend using XAMPP (or WAMP), these are preconfigured PHP, Apache and MySQL servers.

If you're sure you have setup your server correctly check the following:

1. Make sure your executing your files from the server directory and NOT from a local directory. (your URL should look something like "http://localhost/test.php")
   Note: You will need to phisically store the files in a place the apache server will look for, an example from XAMPP (on Windows, as thats what im assuming your using) is: "C:\xampp\htdocs"
2. Make sure your file ends in .php or something else that the Apache server will pickup as a PHP file. (.php3, .php4, etc)(make sure you didn't accidentally leave a .txt or something like that at the very end)
3. Check mod-php module is enabled (as Julien mentioned)

Hope that helps!

Edit:
Try

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

That as well, it should give you the php configuration information if the server is setup correctly.

EDIT2:
I see that you are using XAMPP, double check that the following file exists at the very least:
"C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf", it loads the PHP module

Comment: Yea something is wrong cause that doesn't work. I may try to unistall and xampp and reinstall it again. Weird how stuff works one day and the next day it's all corrupt. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it comes from your web server configuration. If you're using Apache, have you enabled the `mod-php` module?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes its enabled

Comment: I can but Idk where I that is. I'm more of a c# vb guy. Not very handy with php